# Is it safe to change numeric user id on Mac?

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma

Usually what is the number of an user id is not important. But I have use case, where I have a VM running on my Mac, the VM login with my company's LDAP account, so in the VM, the username is same as the username of the Mac local user, but their user IDs are different. I run the VM by VMware Fusion that allows to share host folders into VM. In order to share some folders, to allow the VM and Mac to have the same access to those folders, I am thinking the only way is to update the local user ID to the same number to the LDAP user id. I never did that before, I want to be careful, so I am asking here, is changing a local user's numeric ID safe on Mac? My Mac runs Sonoma.

Comment: What sharing mechanism are you using, and does it _really_ rely on UIDs being the same?

Comment: I use VMware Fusion to run the VM. Fusion allows to share local folder into VM.

Comment: Note that the ID is literally the _identity_ of the user. The name is just a label. So the short version (not very familiar with macOS internals) is that it is very much not “safe” on UNIX/Linux.

Comment: Would be surprised if VMware's sharing mechanism relied on the UIDs matching – it's not "local" file access, more like a network share. Have you encountered problems with the mismatch in practice, or are you only doing this as a precaution?

Comment: As @DanielB has said, plus: As an example of potential chaos, the UID is the key to all file permissions - change UID and files and folders become inaccessible.